# dojo pattern - when to use set/watch and when to use notify/observe?

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo

I'm struggling with a MVC pattern around Stateful objects and Observable stores.  I can't find clarity on when to use one over another and mixing them isn't as clean as I'd hoped.  Any Ah! insight into how to manage an observable collection of stateful items?

If I do a item.set("key", value) I can item.watch("key", cb) but then my observe-er isn't notify-ed.

I can do a item.watch(function() { state.notify(item, item.id); }) to always notify my observer but if my observe-er calls set I get a "Query is out of date, you must observe() the query prior to any data modifications'" error I cannot reconcile.

I can decouple this via a setTimeout but it's not feeling good.

Here's some code to show what I'm trying:

```
    crudify: function ( store, query, crud )
    {
        var result;
        if ( !crud )
        {
            crud = query;
            query = store;
            store = null;
        }
        if ( store )
        {
            query = store.query( query );
        }
        result = query.observe( function ( row, deleteIndex, insertIndex )
        {
            var del = ( 0 <= deleteIndex ), ins = ( 0 <= insertIndex );
            !del && ins && crud.c && crud.c( row );
            del && ins && crud.u && crud.u( row );
            del && !ins && crud.d && crud.d( row );
        }, !!crud.u );
        crud.c && array.forEach( query, crud.c );
        return result;
    }
```

And I have a store wrapper (for layers) which I'm hacking to pieces trying to get the observe-ers notified of data changes without getting errors:

```
addLayer: function ( item ) {
    var that = this;
    that.store.add(item);
    item.watch && item.watch(function (name, prior, curr) {
        if (prior !== curr) {
            that._queue.push(item);
            // attempting to eliminate queries which indirectly update the store (can't find source of error)
            infor.delay(20, "LayerProcessorStoreNotification", function () {
                that._queue.forEach(function (item) {
                    that.store.notify(item, that.getLayerId(item));
                });
                that._queue = [];
            });
        }
    });
    return item;
},
```

The delay method looks like this:

```
    delay: function ( timeout, id, callback )
    {
        this.delays = this.delays || [];
        var delay = this.delays[id];
        if ( delay )
        {
            clearTimeout( delay );
        }
        delay = setTimeout( callback, timeout );
        this.delays[id] = delay;
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can do a item.watch(function() { state.notify(item, item.id); }) to always notify my observer

I didn't have any problems using this pattern, but...

> but if my observe-er calls set I get a "Query is out of date, you must observe() the query prior to any data modifications'" error I cannot reconcile.

You shouldn't have `watch` call `notify` and also have `observe` call `set`.  Choose one or the other.  Otherwise you're setting yourself up for an infinite loop of callbacks.

The code below works for me.  The only change I made to your `crudify` function was to change `array.forEach(query, crud.c)` to `query.forEach(crud.c)`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/dojo-release-1.9.3-src/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.stackoverflow = {
    crudify: function ( store, query, crud )
    {
        var result;
        if ( !crud )
        {
            crud = query;
            query = store;
            store = null;
        }
        if ( store )
        {
            query = store.query( query );
        }
        result = query.observe( function ( row, deleteIndex, insertIndex )
        {
            console.log("Observed");
            var del = ( 0 <= deleteIndex ), ins = ( 0 <= insertIndex );
            !del && ins && crud.c && crud.c( row );
            del && ins && crud.u && crud.u( row );
            del && !ins && crud.d && crud.d( row );
        }, !!crud.u );
        crud.c && query.forEach( crud.c );
        return result;
    }
};

require([
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/Observable",
    "dojo/Stateful",
    "dojo/_base/json",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, Observable, Stateful, dojo){

    var store = Observable(new Memory({ data: [] })); 
    var rawData = [ { id: 1, data: "A" }, { id: 2, data: "B" }, { id: 3, data: "C" }]

    var myQuery = { id : 3 };

    rawData.forEach(function (obj, index) {
      statefulObj = new Stateful(obj);
      statefulObj.watch(function(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log("Watched");
        store.notify(statefulObj, statefulObj.id);
      });                                                            
      store.put(statefulObj);
    });

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        // this directly triggers the observe() callback
        store.notify(store.get(3), 3);
    }, 2000);

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        // this triggers the watch(), which indirectly triggers observe() through notify()
        store.get(3).set("data", "Sea?");
    }, 4000);

    window.setTimeout(function() {                                                     
        // this calls no callbacks because it doesn't match the query                                                             
        store.put({ id: 2, data: "Bee" });
    }, 6000);

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        // this update triggers observe()
        store.put(new Stateful({ id: 3, data: "See!?!" }));

        // note that we didn't set up a watch() on this new object (see below)
    }, 8000);

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        // whoops, this doesn't trigger a callback because we forgot to call watch() above
        store.get(3).set("data", "C4");
    }, 10000);

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        // but the observe() callback still works
        store.notify(store.get(3), 3);
    }, 12000);

    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        // this deletion triggers observe()
        store.remove(3);
    }, 14000);

    stackoverflow.crudify(
        store,
        myQuery,
        {
          u: function(obj) {
            console.log("Observed update: obj: " + dojo.toJson(obj));
          },
          c: function(obj) {
            console.log("Observed creation: obj: " + dojo.toJson(obj));
          },
          d: function(obj) {
            console.log("Observed deletion: obj: " + dojo.toJson(obj));
          }
        });
});
</script>
```